# Storing and Accessing secure information using Android

Tags: java, android, security, authentication, store

I am making a trivia application for Android, and I have an option for keeping the questions offline so that the user can play anywhere. However, I don't have a clue on how to securely store the questions and then securely authenticate the user's answers when they play a game. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: encryption/decryption?

Comment: The short answer is that you can't. Anything you store on the client side can be accessed by the client. Most clients won't bother, but they *could* decompile, unobfuscate, and decrypt anything you give them. If you really want to be secure, then you have to do the processing on a server. Or you could not worry about it, since 99.9% of users won't bother.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm not going to bother right now until my app is completely finished and up in the play store, but i am going to try to encrypting all the data into a file and then using the android keystore for storing the password and then using that to get the data.

Comment: As @KevinWorkman mentioned, anything you store on client side can be accessed by the client. So storing questions on client side securely might not be possible so would securing all possible options for an answer. But you can prevent user from finding out what the correct answer is beforehand. You can do this by storing data client side in the foem <plaintextquestion, <list of possible answers>, Hash of correct answer>. Then you check if the user has given the correct answer by hashing his answer and checking against the Hash of the answer. Again this isnt 100% secure as user can hash [contd]

Comment: [contd] all answers for themselves. The only advantage you have is that they dont know which hashing function youve used and that ***might*** give you an edge